# Getting the current regional format with wmic in windows commandline

Tags: winapi, command-line, localization

"wmic os get locale" gets me the system locale. How do I get the regional format in windows (as this can be different)? If not wmic, is there a way to do this on commandline?

(Regional format: Region and Language -> Formats -> Format dropdown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since WMIC is deprecated (may be it wasn't 8 years ago) I would use PowerShell cmdlet [`Get-Culture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-culture).